# Flutter - How to change Push Notifications background color

Tags: flutter, push-notification, uibackgroundcolor

I was wondering how to change the background color of a push notification? I have seen lately that some other apps like Duolingo change the backgroundcolor of their entire push notification to green. Is there any way to do it in flutter? I have searched on Google and could not find any solution to this problem so far.

Thanks for any help in advance!

[image: picture of another app's push notification]

Comment: Can you put a picture how do they look now?

Comment: Sure, I have just uploaded a picture.

Comment: Any updates on this?